# Android sdk is mssing ,out of date or corrupted

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

I have downloaded latest version of android studio when i click on "create new Project" i get error saying "Android sdk is mssing ,out of date or corrupted".
many has suggested to configure it from project structure but sdk folder is not present in "c:/user/usename/appdata/local/sdk".

Comment: check if it is available in "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk "

Comment: it is not there..even the Android folder itself is not in Local

Comment: its working now..while starting android studio was  stuck at splash screen for that i had added "disable.android.first.run=true " in idea.properties thats'y it was not working .To fix this i changed system language to English(US)

Answer (score 0):

Go to "Settings" and search for sdk.

You'll find it in "Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Android SDK"

Click edit in Android SDK Location.

Choose a location path with no white spaces.

Select all items in the list

Click Next.

SDK components will be downloaded to the specified location

Comment: i tried but after clicking on edit nothing pop-ups ..it should open a window to select the location but it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

If you installed Android Studio and still SDK is not available under below path

> %USERPROFILE%\appdata\Local\Android\sdk

Delete current Android Studio project folder (%USERPROFILE%.AndroidStudio3.0) and relaunch Android Studio, now this time android studio will popup for sdk.

Answer (score 0):

```
Two Solution 
1- Check your old sdk (in your computer)//because android generate automatically path of sdk 
2 -Download latest sdk (online)
```

Comment: i never installed android studio before ..and there is no old sdk present

Comment: many youtube channel to define how to install android studio so please go to youtube and easily download and install sdk

Answer (score 0):

Open "**Project Structure**" by folow steps:

**Android Studio - File - Project Structure** or
**Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S**

Choose "**Dependency**" tab, and in the drop-down list select the desired **Module SDK**.

[image]

---

If list of **Module SDK** is empty, you need download it by follow step:

**Android Studio - File - Other Setting - Settings for New Project**

And choose necessary components

[image]